# How to add objects to NSMutableArray from another array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have an array "names" which contains names starting with letters a, b and c.(like anju,chandu,basha,chitra,amith,baskar)

I have three `NSMutablearray` as,bs and cs.

Now the question is how to get the names from "names" array assign the names starting with letter 'a' to 'as' `mutablearray`, names starting with letter 'b' to 'bs' `mutablearray` and names starting with letter 'c' to 'cs' `mutablearray`?

Could anyone please help..

Thank you.

Comment: Post your current progresses, please.

Comment: only a,b & c or? and post some-code here...

Comment: So you're telling me you don't know how to enumerate an array, test the first character of each string element and then make a decision about which array the string should be added to?  What do you know?

Comment: wow..looks like home assignment given by the lecturer...

Comment: Hint: Use `NSPredicate` on the array like: `SELF beginswith[c] 'a'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this helps you

```
NSArray *namesArray = @[@"anju",@"chandu",@"basha",@"chitra",@"amith",@"baskar"];
NSMutableArray *aArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *bArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSMutableArray *cArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (int j=0; jNSString *string = [namesArray objectAtIndex:j];
        if ([string hasPrefix:@"a"]) {
            [aArray addObject:string];
        }else if([string hasPrefix:@"b"]){
            [bArray addObject:string];
        }else if([string hasPrefix:@"c"]){
            [cArray addObject:string];
        }
}
NSLog(@"---%@----%@----%@",aArray,bArray,cArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will Help you.**

```
for (NSString *thisString in names) {
    if ([thisString characterAtIndex:0] == 'a') {
        [as addObject:thisString];
    }
    else if ([thisString characterAtIndex:0] == 'b') {
        [bs addObject:thisString];
    }
    else if ([thisString characterAtIndex:0] == 'c') {
        [cs addObject:thisString];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
for(int i =;i<names.length;i++){
   NSString *myString =names[i];
   NSString *subString = [myString substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
   if([subString isEqualToString:@"a"){
     [as addObect:subString];
   }else if([subString isEqualToString:@"b"){
     [bs addObect:subString];
   }else if([subString isEqualToString:@"c"){
     [cs addObect:subString];
   }
}
```